# Fluent API Configuration of One-To-Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

When configuring a One-To-Many relationship I usually "only" configure the relationship from one side. But I'm wondering what would be the effect of configuring the relationship from both sides? Is this abundant, ambiguous or does is have any meaningfull effect?

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CurrentGradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API Configuration

```
public class StudentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Students")
                .HasKey(p => p.Id);

            builder
                .HasOne(student  => student.Grade)
                .WithMany(grade => grade.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(student => student.CurrentGradeId)
        }
    }

public class GradeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Grade>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Grade> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Grades")
                .HasKey(p => p.GradeId);

            builder
                .HasMany(grade => grade.Students)
                .WithOne(student => student.Grade)
                .HasForeignKey(student => student.CurrentGradeId)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either.  But not both.  (Although you seem to have swapped the "Has..." code blocks).

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration